# reverse number guess flask w/ wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

After spending last few days over it, i think its time to ask someone. 
Basicaly im trying to make a reverse number guesser in Flask, using WTForms, BUT ive got problem that it works only once: i.e. submiting of form gives result only ONCE.
I've run out of ideas. Will be gratefull for any hints :)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, HiddenField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "SoSecret"

class GuessForm(FlaskForm):

    min_a = 0
    max_a = 1000
    guess = int((max_a - min_a) / 2) + int(min_a)

    pred = SubmitField(guess)
    more = SubmitField('more')
    less = SubmitField('less')
    gjob = SubmitField('gjob')
    minn = HiddenField('min', default=min_a)
    maxx = HiddenField('max', default=max_a)

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():

        form = GuessForm()

        render_template("form.html", form=form)

        if form.more.data and form.validate():
            form.max_a = form.guess
            form.guess = int((form.max_a - form.min_a) / 2) + int(form.min_a)
            return render_template("form.html", form=form)
        elif form.less.data:
            pass
        elif form.gjob.data:
            pass
        return render_template("form.html", form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the html file:

```
<body>

    <form method='POST' action='{{ url_for('form') }}'>
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        I guess the number is {{ form.guess }}
        {{ form.more }}
        {{ form.less }}
        {{ form.gjob }}
        {{ form.minn }}
        {{ form.maxx }}
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only using static values when calculating the next guess, you're never using the buttons inputted by the user!

```
class GuessForm(FlaskForm):

    min_a = 0
    max_a = 1000
    guess = int((max_a - min_a) / 2) + int(min_a)
```

min is always 0, max is always 1000, guess is always 500.

Over here:

```
form.max_a = form.guess
form.guess = int((form.max_a - form.min_a) / 2) + int(form.min_a)
```

all you use is the min, max and the guess, which we determined were already static, so you're not actually using new information given by the user, hence why you're always seeing the same guess.

You need to access, use and update the hidden fields you've already made.

I took some time to fix the route, and it works pretty much as expected now:

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = GuessForm()
    if form.validate():
        if form.more.data:
            form.minn.data = int((int(form.maxx.data) + int(form.minn.data)) / 2)
        elif form.less.data:
            form.maxx.data = int((int(form.minn.data) + int(form.maxx.data)) / 2)
        else:
            return 'yay'
        form.guess = int(int(form.maxx.data) - int(form.minn.data)) / 2 + (int(form.minn.data))
    return render_template("form.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Joost, thank You very much. I insisted on using classes despite the fact I'm just entering those concepts. Took me very long time to even write what I had.